# Avoid delay after Linux mount

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, mount, nfs

I'm executing those commands:

```
mkfs.msdos -C path/to/file/some_file.img 1440

sudo mount -o loop path/to/file/some_file.img /path/to/folder/mounted_folder
```

After those commands, I copy files to mounted_folder and upload the **some_file.img** file to NFS server.

I do it all in Ansible and it happened so fast that **some_file.img** uploaded empty.

I gave it a 5-minute delay and the **some_file.img** was good (with content in it).

I don't want to do it with delay, there is any command I can use to ensure that the **some_file.img** file will upload with the content in it (and not be empty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmount the directory when you're finished to ensure everything is flushed to disk.

```
sudo umount /path/to/folder/mounted_folder
```

Comment: If you unmount it, how will you copy from it?

Comment: The data is in `path/to/file/some_file.img`.